# Magento2 Fatal error: Interface 'Iterator' not found

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I am using Magento 2, when i tried to login from frontend , after submitting login this fatal error is showing

> Fatal error: Interface 'Iterator' not found in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\FileIterator.php
>   on line 15

How to solve this

Comment: Is there any custom module or using a fresh Magento?

Comment: using fresh magento

Comment: Yes its correct, restart the Apache, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same on a local machine and restarting Apache and MySql fixed it.